# Cannot find entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have this DB table which I want to use with JPA

```
CREATE TABLE translations (
id  SERIAL NOT NULL, 
KEY VARCHAR(255), 
LANGUAGE VARCHAR(255), 
TRANSLATION VARCHAR(255)
)
```

I created this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "translations")
public class TranslationTestEntitie extends AbstractEntityWithId {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2029240552230401080L;

    @Column(name = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String key;
    @Column(name = "language", insertable=false, updatable=false)

    private String language;
    @Column(name = "translation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String translation;

    public TranslationTestEntitie() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

}
```

When I try to make this query `SELECT c FROM Translations c WHERE c.Id = 70`

I get this message `The abstract schema type 'Translations' is unknown.`

Is this entitie correct according to the DB table.

P.S This is the code that I use to get the data:

```
public TData td;

    public class TData {

        private long id;
        private String key;
        private String language;
        private String translation;

        public TData() {
        };

        public TData(long id, String key, String language, String translation) {
            // super();
            this.id = id;
            this.key = key;
            this.language = language;
            this.translation = translation;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getTranslation() {
            return translation;
        }

        public void setTranslation(String translation) {
            this.translation = translation;
        }

    }

    public TData getDataObj() {
        return td;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadData() {

        td = new TData();

        String query = "SELECT c FROM Translations c WHERE c.id = 70";
        td = (TData) dao.jpqlQuerySingle(query);//(query);//jpqlQuery(query);

    }
```

But I still get empty Object.

Comment: Have you created this entity manually? Why not to use netbeans/eclipse to generate this using database table structure?

Comment: How do you try to make that query? How to you register your entity type?

Comment: can you post the code that request the db ?

Answer (score 2):

The entity mapped to your `translations` database table has been named `TranslationTestEntitie`.

`from TranslationTestEntitie c` should then suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your table name is not `Translations` but `translations`.

```
SELECT c FROM translations c WHERE c.id = 70
```

And id with lowercase.

Comment: but then this is JPQL so it should be the entity name not table name, as per the JPA spec